# Git post-update hook not working properly

Tags: ssh, git, hook, push, gitlab

If I push to my remote origin repository the post-receive hook should push all to another remote repository on another machine.

When I push to my origin the post-receive hook gets triggered but I always get the following error message.

> remote: post-update started remote: Host key verification failed.
>   remote: fatal: Could not read from remote repository. 
>   remote: 
>   remote: Please make sure you have the correct access rights remote: and the
>   repository exists. 
>   remote: post-update end

Content of post-receive hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "post-update started"
git push --mirror git@<server IP>:root/sample.git
echo "post-update end"
```

I have created a ssh key for my normal user and git user and both were added to authorized keys file.

Something must be missing , but I do not know what?!

Answer (score 0):

The SSH error suggests that the fingerprint of the server's key hasn't been imported in the `.ssh/known_hosts` file yet. You can do this by running `ssh git@<server IP>` manually as the git user on the git server once.

Alternatively you can tell SSH not to check the host key by using the following ssh options:

```
UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

You can add these in your `.ssh/config` file.